# How to make buttons more responsive for touches?

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, keyboard, custom-controls, touchscreen

I am developing a custom touch screen keyboard with Unity. I create all the keys as buttons on Canvas and trigger a function when the button is pressed.

```
public void ButtonPressed() 
{
    string letter = GetComponent<Text>().text;
    inputfield += letter;
}
```

But this way the keyboard is not fully responsive and user interaction is not perfect as expected. How can I improve the buttons responsiveness?

Comment: If your making touch screen then simply [MouseClick](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) Events also response for touch. just use Mouse click events for buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a keyboard i recommend you to put your function on **ButtonDown** not Pressed event.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html

Comment: This is more responsive. Thanks. But the click sound comes a bit delay. Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: @ÇağatayKaya did you find a fix for the sound delay?